# IntelliJ IDEa : saving 'watches' expressions?

Tags: intellij-idea

Does anyone know if there is a way that I can save/persist the expressions I have in the 'Watches' window?

I'm sick of having to always type them back in all the time...

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/adding-editing-and-removing-watches.html) states that *these expressions are persisted as the part of your project.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watches are [not saved](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-42954), it's a known limitation. See also the [related request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64029).